# Implement custom service behavior

Tags: c#, wcf

i try to implement a custom service behavior to get cookies the from the response messages. I've made a breakpoint inside the AfterReceiveRequest method. It gets never hitten. Whats wrong ?
I think need to register my service behavior for a service. How ?

**Behavior :**

```
public class HttpResponseMessageInspector : BehaviorExtensionElement, IDispatchMessageInspector, IServiceBehavior
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {

        //Here is my breakpoint

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Web.config**

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="HttpResponseMessageInspector" type="MyNamespace.HttpResponseMessageInspector, myassembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <HttpResponseMessageInspector/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Service Registration**

```
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Customers", new NinjectWebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CustomersService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Companies", new NinjectWebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(CompaniesService)));
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190806/Send-Cookies-When-Making-WCF-Service-Calls

Comment: Do not. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a class that's implements the `NinjectWebServiceHostFactory` and overwritten the `CreateServiceHost` function.